# wrong cell when changing height

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to change the height of a single cell, which normally would be a piece of cake, but i seem to have a strange behavior. When i change the first cells height, it changes the second cells height. What could be the reason for this?

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)  -> Int {
    return self.categroyArray.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FilterCell") as? FilterCell

    var bottomLine:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, cell!.bounds.height, self.view.frame.width, 1))
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#cecece")
    cell?.addSubview(bottomLine)


    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        var categoryScroll:HMSegmentedControl = HMSegmentedControl(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell!.bounds.width, cell!.bounds.height))
        categoryScroll.sectionTitles = self.categroyArray
        categoryScroll.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
        categoryScroll.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12)
        categoryScroll.selectionStyle = HMSegmentedControlSelectionStyleFullWidthStripe
        categoryScroll.selectionIndicatorColor = UIColor(rgba: "#b44a44")
        categoryScroll.selectedTextColor = UIColor(rgba: "#b44a44")
        categoryScroll.textColor = UIColor(rgba: "#666666")
        categoryScroll.selectionIndicatorLocation = HMSegmentedControlSelectionIndicatorLocationDown
        categoryScroll.segmentEdgeInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)
        categoryScroll.selectionIndicatorHeight = 4
        cell?.addSubview(categoryScroll)

    }

    return cell!
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {


    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 100
    } else {
        return 44
    }

}
```

Illustration:

[image]

Comment: The image looks fine, please add more information.

Comment: What u mean by the image Looks fine? as u can see the second cells height is 100? how come when i applied it to indexPath.row = 0 ?

Comment: Assuming the cells are between the lines (very unclear) it appears that the first cell is about twice the height of the second.

Comment: @Peter Pik We can see *some* cells on the image, there's no information about their rows indexes. So yeah, the image still looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems:

1. You're adding subviews to the cell every time cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called. This is incorrect if you dequeue a cell which already has these subviews.
2. You're relying on the cell's frame/bounds within the same method. However, the table view hasn't set the cell's frame at this point.

You can resolve both of these problems by moving this code out of this method and into the appropriate methods in your cell subclass.

Comment: Yes i moved it to a tableViewCell subclass and used layoutSubviews() to set frame